# Styles and images are not available when installing

Tags: theming

Can't figure out why but all drupal styles and images are not loaded when I'm trying to install it on server. It's obviously a problem with permissions but all directories from root to seven template dir permissions are 755 and template files are all 644 so I guess it should be readable.

UPDATE.
I checked status report and there are two things about files:

> OK File system    Writable (public download method)
>
> If the site is experiencing problems with permissions to content, you
> may have to rebuild the permissions cache. Rebuilding will remove all
> privileges to content and replace them with permissions based on the
> current modules and settings. Rebuilding may take some time if there
> is a lot of content or complex permission settings. After rebuilding
> has completed, content will automatically use the new permissions.

Comment: Did u Check the status report?

Comment: where can i watch it?

Comment: Ok,i've found it. Updated the question.